# HttpWebRequest - Redirect

Tags: .net, vb.net

I would like to get the `HTML` code from the page:
http://trendstop.knack.be/nl/detail/446121707/6x-international.aspx
but each time I make the `HTML` request using:

```
  Imports System
  Imports System.IO
  Imports System.Web
  Imports System.Net
  Imports System.IO.IsolatedStorage
  Imports System.Threading
  Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
  Imports System.Text

  Public Class GetSource
      Function GetHTML(ByVal strPage As String) As String
          Dim strReply As String = "NULL"

    Try
        Dim objHttpRequest As System.Net.HttpWebRequest
        Dim objHttpResponse As System.Net.HttpWebResponse
        objHttpRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(strPage)


        objHttpResponse = objHttpRequest.GetResponse

        Dim objStrmReader As New StreamReader(objHttpResponse.GetResponseStream)

        strReply = objStrmReader.ReadToEnd()

    Catch ex As Exception
        strReply = "ERROR! " + ex.Message.ToString
    End Try

          Return strReply

      End Function


  End Class
```

I get the html of the redirected url http://trendstop.knack.be/nl/detail/446121707/6x-international/activity.aspx

How can I obtain the html code of the original `url`?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you would like to set the AllowAutoRedirect property to 'false'?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.allowautoredirect.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to a Useragent problem. Some sites tries to read your user agent and redirect if certain values arent available.

Have you tried setting a user agent? Do you still get redirected?

```
objHttpRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
```

Comment: I added the useragent but he still redirects me. When I use objHttpRequest.autoredirect = false he ends up with:

<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/nl/detail/446121707/6x-international.aspx">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>

Comment: If you add a MsgBox(objHttpResponse.ResponseStatus) before he reads the page, what is the nr you get?

Comment: I added MsgBox(objHttpResponse.StatusCode) and got status OK (200, this is with the autoredirect set to true. When I set the autoredirect to false he gives the status FOUND (302).

But he is allowed to redirect me to "http://trendstop.knack.be/nl/detail/446121707/6x-international.aspx" but not to "http://trendstop.knack.be/nl/detail/446121707/6x-international/activity.aspx".

This is the code he gives me with autoredirect to false:
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/nl/detail/446121707/6x-international/activity.aspx">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>

Comment: I will give it a try myself i have some time today.

Comment: Ive been trying for some time but get the same problem. Im wondering if it has anything to do with the settings of the server where website is hosted, or if its a asp.net setting that has a presetted value. Hard to determine.

Comment: Ive tried a lot of this but until now stil the same problem.
I came across of a forum with the same issue discuttion and the solution provided was:

-------------------------------------

 we need to scrape the page included in the HTTP "location" header again to retrieve its correct content.

-------------------------------------------------

but I don't have any clue how to implement this in my code.

Comment: Hmm. Going to need to fire up Fiddler, watch the requests between the browser and webpage manually, then recreate the headers (should be trivial...something like a Dictionary or array in my experience, that gets tacked onto the object). I'm half-tempted to do this myself, but have a 'full' schedule as is...perhaps later, if I have time?

Comment: CHecked with Fiddler, the page I'm getting in between before the redirection is 'Object moved here'. I believe I need to make a 'POST' fist and then a 'GET'. Does anybody have any experience with making 'POST' requests?